# Create mean raster stack from raster stack

Tags: python, raster, gdal, statistics

I am trying to create a mean stack image(1 panchromatic layer) from a stacked tiff image(13 panchromatic layers). How do i go about doing this?

My code:

```
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np

#read ndvi_stack layers
ndvi_stack = gdal.Open('NDVI_stack/ndvi_stack.tif') 
bands = ndvi_stack.RasterCount

for band in range(1, bands+1):
    data = ndvi_stack.GetRasterBand(band).ReadAsArray().astype('float')
    mean = np.mean(data[data != 0]) #calculate mean without value 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you are calculating a mean value for each band. However you likely want to get a mean value for each set of values in the same pixel in your `ndvi_stack` image.

One way to accomplish this is to create a 3D `numpy array` using [`np.stack()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) and then calculating the mean by specifying the axis.

```
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np

#read ndvi_stack layers
ndvi_stack = gdal.Open('NDVI_stack/ndvi_stack.tif')
bands = ndvi_stack.RasterCount

ndvi_array = []  # list to store all the bands
for band in range(1, bands+1):
    data = ndvi_stack.GetRasterBand(band).ReadAsArray().astype('float')  # (n rows by n cols array)
    ndvi_array.append(data)

ndvi_array = np.stack(ndvi_array)  # (n bands by n rows by n cols array)
result = ndvi_array.mean(axis=0)  # (n rows by n cols array)
```

I see you are trying to ignore zeros when calculating the mean. Following the same principle from the code above, you can use a [masked numpy array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html) to accomplish this. The only differences is that you mask the array to ignore zeros and calculate the mean using [`np.ma.mean()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.mean.html) rather than `np.mean()`.

```
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np

#read ndvi_stack layers
ndvi_stack = gdal.Open('NDVI_stack/ndvi_stack.tif')
bands = ndvi_stack.RasterCount

ndvi_array = []  # list to store all the bands
for band in range(1, bands+1):
    data = ndvi_stack.GetRasterBand(band).ReadAsArray().astype('float')  # (n rows by n cols array)
    ndvi_array.append(data)

ndvi_array = np.stack(ndvi_array)  # (n bands by n rows by n cols array)
ndvi_array = np.ma.array(ndvi_array, mask=(ndvi_array == 0))  # masked array
result = np.ma.mean(ndvi_array, axis=0)  # (n rows by n cols array)
```

Furthermore, if there are pixels where all the bands have a value of 0, you will end up with masked pixels, represented with a `--` when you print the array. You can easily convert all the masked pixels to an arbitrary value (e.g. a NoData value) using:
`result = result.filled(-99)`, replacing `-99` with the value of your choice.

After you have the result, which is a `numpy array`, you will have to create a raster dataset, write the array to the first band of the raster and save it.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked a charm!!